# How to upgrade php version in uWamp

Tags: wordpress, uwamp

Trying to initiate local Wordpress i got the message :
Votre serveur utilise la version 5.6.18 de PHP mais WordPress 5.2 nécessite au moins la version 5.6.20.
How can I solve the problem
Thanks and Regards

Comment: You should update your php version from your local machine. Maybe you can use xampp, they use more recent versions of PHP

Answer (score 5):

After a few failures I finally managed to make php-7.4.24 and php-8.0.10 run - and it's very easy!

1. Go to the [PHP Windows Download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65439854/adding-php-v8-0-to-uwamp-3-1-0) Page.
2. Get the **x86 Thread Safe** version(s)
3. UnZIP to a (in my case) php-7.4.23 and php-8.0.10 folder
4. Add this lines to `httpd_uwamp.conf` around line 166:

   Define {PHPMODULENAME} {PHPMODULENAME}

> ```
> <IfDefine php8_module>
> LoadModule php_module "{PHPPATH}/{PHPAPACHE2FILE}"
> </IfDefine>
> <IfDefine php7_module>
> LoadModule {PHPMODULENAME} "{PHPPATH}/{PHPAPACHE2FILE}"
> </IfDefine>
> <IfDefine php5_module>
> LoadModule {PHPMODULENAME} "{PHPPATH}/{PHPAPACHE2FILE}"
> </IfDefine>
> ```

5. Start UwAmp.
6. It will find the new php versions and ask if you want to install, say yes, and choose the production ini

Code sample is [from this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65439854/adding-php-v8-0-to-uwamp-3-1-0)

Answer (score 1):

You can update PHP version within the control panel of uWamp. 
also you can install manually any version that you want and uWamp will recognize.

[uWamp screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jTnrv.png)

Answer (score 0):

After manually upgrading php to version 7.4.9 in uWamp there is a warning in phpMyAdmin. This is caused by a too old version of phpMyAdmin in uWamp. After upgrading phpMyAdmin to version 4.9.5 the warnig in phpAdmin has been gone.

Answer (score 0):

As a note, you might simply copy over an existing php_uwamp.ini file into the new PHP folder to retain the customizations you have. Please bear in mind that when switching to a new MAJOR version (v7 to v8) the .ini may have changed.