# Adding PHP v8.0 to UwAmp 3.1.0

Tags: uwamp

I've successfully added PHP v8.0 to my stable of PHP versions runnning under UwAmp 3.1.0. Since PHP v8.0 changes the name of the apache php module to simply 'phpmodule' wiithout the major version number, the httpd_uwamp.conf file must be updated replacing the line loading the {PHPMODULENAME} with the following:

```
    Define {PHPMODULENAME} {PHPMODULENAME}
    <IfDefine php8_module>
    LoadModule php_module "{PHPPATH}/{PHPAPACHE2FILE}"
    </IfDefine>
    <IfDefine php7_module>
    LoadModule {PHPMODULENAME} "{PHPPATH}/{PHPAPACHE2FILE}"
    </IfDefine>
    <IfDefine php5_module>
    LoadModule {PHPMODULENAME} "{PHPPATH}/{PHPAPACHE2FILE}"
    </IfDefine>
```

Comment: It would've been better to post the question and answer separately, not as the same post, then accept your answer or some other one if it's better.

Comment: This worked for me - many thanks, no idea how you found out

Comment: Thanks, worked well on php version 7.4.28, shut down the server, unzip in bin/php folder, replaced the lines mentioned in bin/apache/conf/httpd_uwanp.conf, restart and say yes, we used development setup. We noticed that the panel jumped back to the first version in the list (5.6x) after the restart. So, just choose the 7.4 in the dropdown and EVERYTHING worked without any copy and paste of other files. However, php 8.x might differ.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the advice!

I had trouble doing the same. I write this before trying the following, in case I forget to post it afterwards, and someone else needs the same help.

I tried replacing line 166 of `httpd_uwamp.conf`, which contains the text `LoadModule {PHPMODULENAME} "{PHPPATH}/{PHPAPACHE2FILE}"`. Apparently, I also need to copy the `php_uwamp.ini` from the old PHP version to the new version. In `/bin/`, there is a folder `php` for the PHP versions, a folder `databases` for the MySQL versions, and a folder `apache` which I don't think we should touch.

Here are the contents of a relevant comment from a different quesiton:

> I always add MySQL and MariaDB versions (32 bit) as they are released. I simply shut down my DB server, extract the new version package into a new folder within bin/database, then I copy the 'data' folder and the my_uwamp.ini file. Once the copy is completed, I bring up the new DB server, make sure I can log in with the existing UwAmp passwords, then run the mysql_upgrade command line utility in the new db version 'bin' folder.

It would be nice if someone made a video guide or more detailed guide about how to do those things, or maybe even an utility to make UWamp usable with newer versions (like patching the file you mentioned, installing other versions of PHP, other versions of MySQL, and other compatible database systems.

---

*Links to different questions related to this one:*

[How to upgrade php version in uWamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61229550/how-to-upgrade-php-version-in-uwamp)

[How to upgrade MySQL in UwAmp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61937968/how-to-upgrade-mysql-in-uwamp)

Answer (score 0):

Open `UwAmp\bin\apache\conf\httpd_uwamp.conf` and find this line:

```
LoadModule {PHPMODULENAME} "{PHPPATH}/{PHPAPACHE2FILE}"
```

Replace that line with the following block:

```
Define "{PHPMODULENAME}"
<IfDefine php8_module>
    LoadModule php_module "{PHPPATH}/{PHPAPACHE2FILE}"
</IfDefine>
<IfDefine !php8_module>
    LoadModule {PHPMODULENAME} "{PHPPATH}/{PHPAPACHE2FILE}"
</IfDefine>
```