# Support to PHP 7.1 and higher

Tags: php, wordpress, redux-framework, uwamp

I am using uWamp for our localserver (USB Drive) site designed and developed in WordPress. We are using Redux framework for our Website and this framework requires PHP 7.1. Is uWamp available with PHP 7.1 I tried installing PHP 7.1 or higher separately. uWamp is detecting it and installing but Apache server does not start.

Any solution how I can use uWamp with php 7.1 or higher.

Comment: I would suggest contacting their support about this, but it looks like some versions support PHP 7.2 and higher on https://www.uwamp.com/en/?page=download

Answer (score 0):

today I tried UwAmp for the first time and figured out how to install php_7.4.33.
Download the version from [here](https://windows.php.net/download#php-8.1), scroll down and select "VC15 x86 Thread Safe".
Unzip the downloaded file to "C:\UwAmp\bin\php" (adapt to your installation directory!) and start UwAmp.
It will ask you for the php.ini, confirm the preselected "php.ini-development" and it's done.
**Notice**: for me only the Thread Safe 32-bit version worked.
Tried also with the Non Thread Safe and 64-bit version but ended up with Apache starting and stopping immediately.
Also the php_8.1.12 didn't work for me, but this is the one I need to get to work.
So I will go on with testing ...
Oh, forgot to mention: php_7.2.7 can be installed directly from within UwAmp.
**EDIT 2022-11-10:**
Got it working with php_8.1.12!
Download and unzip php_8 repeating the steps I described for version php_7.4.33. Then go to your "C:\UwAmp\bin\php\php-8.1.12" folder and open the file "php8apache2_4.dll" with a Hex-Editor.
Now search for "php8apache2_4.dll.jump_fcontext.make_fcontext.php_module" in the decoded text and change the last part in "php8_module".
Save, DONE!!
Now you only have to change the PHP version in UwAmp and check if Apache keeps running.
Happy developing, happy testing!

Comment: Thanks for replying, but I am still facing issues in using uWamp for 8.1.x. I tried changing the .dll through hex editor. but, it is not fixing the issue. See the screenshot for error message.
[uWamp application with error for 8.1.x][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7CvU.png

Comment: You have multiple problems: to get rid of the first one (mysqld -> Windows event log) do as describe in the error and start UwAmp with mouse right click -> execute as administrator. 
For the PHP8 problem maybe you will try this other solution I've found here on stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65439854/adding-php-v8-0-to-uwamp-3-1-0, but use do not use the modified .dll - take the original.
Good luck!

Comment: Additional comment: you used the 64bit version, for me only the 32bit version worked, just as I mentioned in my answer.